# List manipulation with foldr in Racket

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, racket, fold

`#lang racket`

I need to create a list from 2 lists

```
list1 => '(1 2 3)
list2 => '(a b c)
```

desired result of

```
(define (create-list l1 l2)
...
)
```

to be `'((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))`

must use `foldr` and cannot use recursion.

I was thinking about running a counter and using list-ref,
is there a better way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Racket, the [`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) higher-order procedure can take multiple lists as arguments, you just have to craft a `lambda` that processes them as required:

```
(define (create-list l1 l2)
  (foldr (lambda (e1 e2 acc)
           (cons (list e1 e2) acc))
         '() l1 l2))
```

For example:

```
(create-list '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
=> '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
```

Comment: @LenaBru It's just a name. This parameter serves as the accumulator, where the response is being built and eventually, returned at the end.